# MEAN, actualizar elemento, /users

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Como puedo actualizar un elemento en updateUser?, seria con el indice y hago un push en ese indice? no tengo mucha idea

esto es lo que tengo intentando

```
exports.updateUser= function(req,res){
  var userId = req.params.userId;
  var name= req.body.name;
  var desc= req.body.desc;
  for(var userIndex in users){
    var user= users[userIndex];
    if(user.id==userId){
      users[userIndex]={"name":name,"desc": desc,"img":"htpp://localhost:3000/public/jg.jpg"};
    }
  }
    res.send(users);
};
```

y este es el codigo total

```
var users =[
      {"id":"1", "name":"Juan Garcia", "desc":"Le encanta el sol y los paseos por la playa", "img":"htpp://localhost:3000/public/jg.jpg" },
      {"id":"2", "name":"Jose Garcia", "desc":"Le encanta la luna y los paseos por la playa", "img":"htpp://localhost:3000/public/jg.jpg" },
      {"id":"3", "name":"Julian Garcia", "desc":"Le encanta martes y los paseos por la playa", "img":"htpp://localhost:3000/public/jg.jpg" },
      {"id":"4", "name":"Josefa Garcia", "desc":"Le encanta jupiter y los paseos por la playa", "img":"htpp://localhost:3000/public/jg.jpg" }
    ]

    exports.getUsers = function(req,res){
      res.send(users);
    }

    exports.addUser = function(req,res){
      var name= req.body.name;
      var desc= req.body.desc;

      users.push({"name":name,"desc": desc,"img":"htpp://localhost:3000/public/jg.jpg"});

      res.send(users);
    };

    exports.updateUser= function(req,res){
      //No se como hacerlo
    };

    exports.deleteUser = function(req,res){
      var userId = req.params.userId;

      for(var userIndex in users){
        var user= users[userIndex];
        if(user.id==userId){
          users.splice(userIndex,1);
        }
      }
      res.send(users);
    };
```

Comment: actializo ahora mismo con lo que tengo intentado

Comment: Perfecto! Puedes añadir qué problema tienes con el codigo intentado?  Cual es el resultado esperado? cual es el resultado obtenido con el mismo? Algun error en consola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la idea correcta pero usas el método inadecuado.

Estás usando un bucle [*for ... in*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in), que de acuerdo a la documentación sirve para recorrer elementos (atributos) de un objeto en un orden arbitrario.

Tu variable ***users*** es un tipo `Array`, y cada elemento de este `Array` es un objeto.

Para poder iterar cada elemento de tu `Array` de usuarios podrías usar un bucle [*for*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for) estándar, un bucle [*for...of*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) o el método [*forEach()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) del tipo `Array`.

Además, veo que en tu método `addUser` no realizas la actualización al campo `id`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Como ya mencioné, usas el método inadecuado. Una forma en la que tu programa podría funcionar sería la siguiente:

```
exports.updateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body) { // verificamos que se han recibido datos
    const userId = req.params.userId; // capturamos el id
    const name = req.body.name; // capturamos los valores
    const desc = req.body.desc;
    let updated = false; // esta variable indicara el tipo de respuesta devuelta
    for(let user of users) { // usamos un bucle for of
      if(user.id == userId) {
        user.name = name || user.name; // en caso que no se vaya a reemplazar el valor
        user.desc = desc || user.desc;
        updated = !updated; // actualizamos
        break; // no necesitamos seguir buscando por id
      }
    }
    if(updated) { // si la actualizacion sucedio enviamos la respuesta
      return res.status(201).json(users);
    } else { // si no se actualizo enviamos un mensaje
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'No user found for id: ' + userId
      });
    }
  }
  return res.status(500).json({ // si no se reciben datos se envia el mensaje correspondiente
    error: 'No data'
  });
}
```

De esta forma debes poder actualizar el usuario.

En cuanto a tu método para crear un usuario, puedes hacer lo siguiente para escribir el campo `id`. Aunque normalmente el campo `id` es un campo autogenerado cuando usas un sistema de almacenamiento en base de datos (MongodB, MySQL, FireBase, etc.), para este ejercicio tan sencillo podrías incrementar en 1 unidad el valor más alto del campo `id` de tus documentos.

Una forma sencilla de implementarlo sería la siguiente:

```
exports.addUser = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body) { // verificamos que se reciben los datos
    const name = req.body.name; // establecemos los valores
    const desc = req.body.desc;
    let id = 0; // el valor del `id` que deseamos crear, se inicia en 0
    users.forEach((user) => { // recorremos todo el Array
      let userId = parseInt(user.id);  // convertimos a entero
      if(userId > id) { // comparamos
        id = userId; // asignamos
      }
    });
    // al terminar el bucle, la variable id tendrá el valor mas alto existente
    users.push({id: (id + 1).toString(), name: name, desc: desc}); // añadimos 1 unidad a id para crear un nuevo elemento.
    return res.status(201).json(users);
  }
  return res.status(500).json({
    error: 'No data'
  });
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda. Saludos